# rails initialize methode in model or controller? Rails Test Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, model, initialization

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and I'm working at my first project. I'm not a native english speaker, so I failed looking up at google. First I would like to know, if u declare a initialize method, for a Class like:

```
def initialize(attributes = {})
@name = attributes[:name]
@email = attributes[:email]
end
```

Or like:

```
class Person
 def initialize(name, age)
  @name, @age = name, age
 end
end
```

Do i have to delcare that method in the controller or in the model of the corresponding Class?

Is it true that we use instance Variables (@name or  @age) just in the Controller? The intance Variables for our models we declare in the migration files right? like:

```
class CreateStudents < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def up
  create_table :students do |t|
   t.string :prename, :limit => 100, :null=>false
   t.string :lastname, :limit => 100, :null=>false
   t.date :birthday, :null => false
   t.text :contact
   t.boolean :daz, :null => false, :default => false
   t.integer :form_id

   t.timestamps null: false
 end
end

def down
 drop_table :students
end
```

end

My last question is about the Test files in rails.
I read something like this: 
    require 'test_helper'

```
class StudentTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "hello" do
    stud = Student.new
    assert_not stud.save
  end
end
```

When i run "rake test", it got this Error:

```
yannick@Yannux ~/SchulDatenbank $ rake test
Running via Spring preloader in process 5041
Run options: --seed 16904

# Running:

E

Finished in 0.032498s, 30.7711 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

  1) Error:
StudentTest#test_hello:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::ConstraintException: 
NOT NULL constraint failed: students.prename: INSERT INTO 
"students" ("created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES 
('2017-03-18 14:04:40', '2017-03-18 14:04:40', 980190962)


1 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

then i tried something like:
    require 'test_helper'

```
class StudentTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "hello" do
    assert true
  end
end
```

Same Error...
Does anyone know why? :)
Thank u for help

Answer (score 0):

You are using db constraint in your migration for "pername" (null: false).
Therefore, you got error when you call *stud.save* in your test, because your stud is trying to save stud record in db with blank pername field. Maybe, would be better to use *valid?* insted of *save* :)

Comment: Thx for help, but when i test something like this:  test "hello" do
    stud = Student.new
    stud.prename = "Gustav"
    stud.lastname = "Meyer"
    stud.birthday = "30.05.1992".to_date
    stud.add_to_form(3,"A")
    assert stud.save
  end  I get exactly the same Error